# What is the best way to put comments section to user profile

Tags: users, comments

I need add ability to add comment for user profile. What i am thinking is, create a content type with empty body and leave just comments, and afterwards insert that node to user_profile.
But i don't know how to append comments to user profile tpl file. How to do this, or maybe other suggestions?

> After some research i decided to make my own module to add comments on
>   user profile, i will make a block and insert this block to only user
>   page *user/**, and will track user id to show proper comments.

Comment: Do you use profile2 module ? what is your drupal version?

Comment: yes i have profile2 module, drupal version 7

Answer (score 2):

If you use [Profile2](http://drupal.org/project/profile2), this creates profiles as node type entities so you can turn comments on as each profile will have settings similar to that when you create content types.

Comment: there is not setting for add comment ,`admin/structure/profiles/add` or in `admin/structure/profiles/manage/test` . profile  not support commenting by default

Comment: My bad, just tried and you are correct there is no option. My answer is how it used to work for Drupal 6

Comment: any other suggestions?

Comment: You could look at http://drupal.org/project/reply but this is in dev

Answer (score 1):

If you want add comment to profile  in template files, do you  think how you want realate those with eachothers?
I suggest you using modules like [commentfield](http://drupal.org/project/commentfield) . install and add a comment field in your profile type.

Your right,  please look at this [issue](http://drupal.org/node/1461302) and [this](http://drupal.org/node/245251)

Comment: in this module you cannot add comments on a view page

Comment: I said some module like it ,as example [reply](http://drupal.org/project/reply)